# In Perl can I create a test in one file that only runs after a test in another file has run?

Tags: perl, testing

I am running test files on a Perl module I have written and I would like to have a condition where some tests are only run after others have been run successfully (but still keeping them in separate files).

I was looking at [Test::Builder](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/Builder.html), but I don't think it caters for cross-file testing.

Just to explain why I want to do this; I have a test file for every subroutine in my module. Some of these subroutines are passed large hashes from other subroutines which are difficult to replicate for testing purposes.

So instead of spending a few hours trying to hard-code a testable hash, I would like to be passed one from the code like it would be, only after the subroutine where that hash has been generated is tested.

I hope that makes sense! I could write a script to just run the tests in a certain order, but thought that there may well already be a feature in a Perl testing module that I haven't seen. When it comes to using the module, I ideally want to be able to run the tests without having to fiddle about with the 'make test' bit.

Comment: How about [Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Test-Simple-0.98/lib/Test/More.pm)?

Comment: I already use that, but I haven't seen a feature that is good for testing over multiple files, unless I've over looked it.

Comment: (1) Assumption questioning time:  Why do you need to supply the subsequent tests with a full-size data set rather than one you've invented for testing purposes?  Are you testing their ability to handle large inputs? (2) Generally, the desire to run tests in a particular order is a design smell:  There is something wrong with your design that is causing you to experience this desire, and you would be better served spending time on solving the design problem than trying to hack around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Perl test harness seems to run test files in alphabetical order. This is why so many CPAN distributions have test files that start with numbers - so that the author can control the order of test execution. That will break if, for example, someone runs those tests with `prove -s`.

In general a test file should be seen as a completely separate unit of testing. You should be able to run all of your tests in any order without any of them affecting any of the others. If two tests rely on each other then they should be in the same file.

You haven't explained why you're so keen for these tests to be in separate files. Perhaps that's the assumption that you should be questioning.

Comment: Thanks, you have a good point. The main reason I have for 'a-test-file-per-subroutine' is that I keep tweaking different subroutines and don't want to test the whole program just to find out if a small part of it works. 

The first couple of subs crunch large amounts of data which is hard to replicate so it would be nice to be able to run those tests once and (if passed) have the other subs tested whenever I want, hence why I put them in a different file. I think I'll just have to keep them in the same file again.